# Slicing using slice() without a stop value

Tags: python

Is there an equivalent for `[:]` using python's built-in `slice` class?

```
In [8]: 'abcdef'[:3]
Out[8]: 'abc'

In [9]: 'abcdef'[slice(3)]
Out[9]: 'abc'

In [10]: 'abcdef'[:]
Out[10]: 'abcdef'

In [11]: 'abcdef'[slice()]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-9afb03fec62a> in <module>()
----> 1 'abcdef'[slice()]

TypeError: slice expected at least 1 arguments, got 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `None`, the default:

```
>>> 'abcdef'[:]
'abcdef'
>>> 'abcdef'[None:]
'abcdef'
>>> 'abcdef'[None:None]
'abcdef'
>>> 'abcdef'[None:None:None]
'abcdef'
>>> 'abcdef'[slice(None)]
'abcdef'
>>> 'abcdef'[slice(None, None)]
'abcdef'
>>> 'abcdef'[slice(None, None, None)]
'abcdef'
```

Comment: I see, unfortunately in `numpy` the behaviour is not consistent, `None` meaning `np.newaxis`. `slice(None)` does work though. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Sure, any of the following would be equivalent:

```
>>> seq = [1,2,3,4]
>>> seq[slice(None)]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> seq[slice(None, None)]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> seq[slice(None, None, None)]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```